# CardView in ConstraintLayout Not Wrapping Height

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

CardView in ConstraintLayout Not Wrapping Height.

Facing the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834475/constraintlayout-not-wrapping-content) with stable CL library:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

Android Studio: 2.3.2

Observations:

1. Setting hardcoded cardview-height fixes the issue.
2. Changing CardView with RelativeLayout fixes.

Is there still an [`issue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938767/designing-cardview-while-its-parent-is-constraintlayout) with Cardview that it is finding hard to cope up with ConstraintLayout.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/io15_blue_grey_100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mobLeftIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_up" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/mobLeftIcon"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Mobile Number"
                    android:text="123123123" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phoneLeftIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_up" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/phoneLeftIcon"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mobInputLayout">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Telphone Number"
                    android:text="123123123" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I have the similar issue.
The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126724/constraintlayout-in-cardview-adding-white-space) fix my issue.

Answer (score 4):

To make CardView wrap content represented by ConstraintLayout, you have to add 3 chains to views inside ConstraintLayout:

1. Horizontal spread chain between mobLeftIcon and mobInputLayout
2. Horizontal spread chain between phoneLeftIcon and phoneInputLayout
3. Vertical spread chain between mobInputLayout and phoneInputLayout

See this screenshot of Layout Editor:

[image: Chains on Layout Editor]

---

Here's the **final source code** for your layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mobLeftIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_up"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mobLeftIcon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Mobile Number"
                    android:text="123123123" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/phoneLeftIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_up"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/phoneInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mobInputLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/phoneLeftIcon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Telphone Number"
                    android:text="123123123" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a **result**, you get something like:

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
```

You can use the height as 0dp and use the line

```html
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```